# Set mysql engine for flyway 'schema_version' table

Tags: mysql, flyway

When I run a flyway migration for the first time on a cluster, I see that the flyway auto-generated table `schema_version` is created using the `innodb` engine instead of the `ndbcluster` engine. Because of this, the `schema_version` is only created on the active db node.

Is there anyway to to tell flyway to create this table using the ndbcluster engine so it is automatically propagated to all nodes in the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You'll have to create the table yourself.